# Gsuite email not working with Google Cloud Platform when I change the domain (Google Domains) to point to GCP nameservers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-dns

The cloud DNS on GCP is `ns-cloud-a1:googledomains.com` while the default nameservers for Google Domains is `NS-CLOUD-C1.googledomains.com` -

If I change the domain nameservers to point to `ns-cloud-a1:googledomains.com`, the domain will work on the GCP instance, but Gsuite emails will no longer work for the domain. Gsuite will work if I leave the nameservers default but the domain will not work with the VM instance.

I am sure something is being overlooked on my part. I am looking for a solution.

Comment: Have you checked your MX Records?

Answer (score 0):

When you change your NS to GCP. You have to replicate all of your records in GCP (Cloud DNS section). E.g. for email delivery, you need to add MX records as per this article: https://support.google.com/a/answer/140034?hl=en

When this will done, it might take up to 48 hours of propagation delay. However, usually it's much faster (hours).